# Exit Chrome Extension w/ Background Permissions on Browser Close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome extension that requires background permissions in order to be able to stream music with the extension closed. I run a script in the background that creates an audio element and plays music, and the [foreground] extension can play/pause. However, when the user exits the browser, the controls go with it! Because of the very nature of background permissions, the extension keeps running and streaming music. But the user can no longer stop it without reopening Chrome.

Please tell me there's a way around this? I want my extension to play music when the extension is not in the foreground, but I also want to quit/stop when the user exists the main Chrome window. To be clear, this is not a background "page" running, it's a javascript file.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the background permission to have a background script. Just remove the permission from your manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the background permission to have a background script. You can simply remove the `background` permission from your manifest.